# How to put a big text box in a HTML form instead of a single line?

Tags: html, forms, textbox

I am trying to make a contact form and I need to have a big text box for people to explain their inquiry in detail. Currently I am using:

```
<div class="formField">
   <label for="contactType2"> Details about your inquiry </label>
      <input type="text" 
      name="contactType2"
      id="contactType"
      required></input>
</div>
```

But this only shows up as a single line due to the text input being a small box. How do I fix this?

I have tried to look through the other inputs VSC offers but I don't see one that would fix this problem. I also have the pre-written code above

Answer (score 0):

Use textArea for inquiry detail.

```
<textarea id="inquiry" name="inquiry" rows="4" cols="50">Add your inquiry</textarea>
```

Refer below link for learn more
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use the `textarea` tag.

```html
<textarea id="id" name="name" placeholder="Type your text">Replace this text</textarea>
```